# jquery mobile button color change

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

i have a question and i know that is not the best question on this portal.

but my problem is that i have on my mobile app 2 libraries of jquery and jquery mobile..

and know the buttons i have added have change the color from black to white.. why?

here are my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

<a href="#myPanel" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse">Search</a>
```

Comment: Which jQuery Mobile version are you using?

Comment: always was black,, only today i open my app and the buttons are white

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today's version of jQuery Mobile css file has an error and style is not applied to your buttons. Advice, never use latest jQuery Mobile files.

For now use this stable 1.3.1 version:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Stable version: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nx5hm/

Latest unstable version: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/2excE/

Comment: and you have right.i have change the libraries and works how i had before.. thanks a lot

Comment: You are using jQuery Mobile version developers are using for development, it is usually an unstable version.